# Организовать хранение изображений с последующим доступом по ссылке

Tags: .net, ubuntu, файловая-система, микросервисы, ftp-сервер

Решил попробовать реализовать простенькое микросервисное приложение в целях обучения.
Приложение пишется на .net core

Так же имеется сервер Ubuntu, на котором планируется хранить изображения.

Есть микросервис, который обеспечивает всю работу связанную с профилями.

Что хочется реализовать:

1. клиентское приложение отправляет в микросервис данные (ФИО, дата рождения, изображение, etc)
2. сервис сохраняет данные в своей БД, а картинку на внешнее хранилище.
3. клиентское приложение просит данные о пользователе
4. сервис возвращает JSON с информацией о пользователе и с изображением в виде ссылки, например "http://storage.ru/images/avatar.jpg"
5. на клиенте ссылка вставляется в 'img src="http://storage.ru/images/avatar.jpg"

Так собственно в чем суть вопроса, как реализовать **сохранение** изображений в сервисе на внешнее хранилище и дальнейшее **получение их по ссылке**.

Больше всего интересует как сделать так, чтобы доступ к файлам на сервере Ubuntu был по URL ссылке.

Так же буду благодарен за какие то альтернативные способы.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Надо начать с того что принять решение как изображения попадают в микросервис. Если по http. то сделать обработчик запроса на загрузку файла, который получит содержимое и положит его на внешнее хранилище, тем способом, который требует это самое хранилище. И лучше загрузку картинки отделить от передачи остальных данных о пользователе. Например сначала создаете пользователя, возвращаете id, а на загрузку картинки передаете только этот id

Comment: Mike, спасибо за ответ. Да, по http, пока остановился на варианте передавать base64 строку и дальше в байт массив и сохранять как файл. Отдельные методы учту. Самый наверное главный вопрос как раз в том как реализовать именно физический процесс сохранения файла на сервер, т.е со стороны сервера Ubuntu. Например создаем там ftp хранилище, а как в него удаленно сохранять файлы и получать их по URL ссылке не понимаю и найти вразумительных ответов не смог, возможно как то неправильно искал...